# System.Speech.Synthesis CultureInfo for exe

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to use `System.Speech.Synthesis;` with french female voice, but still got english male.

```
    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Adult, 0,
      new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"));

    synth.Speak("bonjour le monde");
```

I did not installed nothing yet, just added reference system.speech, so now I found this to download and install:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

but first of all I need to know if I can use it with different languages for executable for other users, not sure how it works with different languages

also I need to install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225

and there is two:

***For the Runtime, please download the Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime 11***

**x86_SpeechPlatformRuntime\SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi**

and

**x64_SpeechPlatformRuntime\SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi**

which says:

*The Microsoft Speech Platform Runtime contains both a managed (.NET) and native (COM) API for developing Server based speech applications.*

So if my system 62-bit, which I have to install to make it available for other users, or I have to install it only according to my system x86

and another:

***For the Software Development Kit, please download the Microsoft Speech Platform - SDK 11***

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

*This software development kit contains the documentation, development resources, tools and samples for development of speech applications that utilize the Microsoft Speech Platform Runtime 11.*

So what the difference if I want use it for application executable?

Comment: SelectVoiceByHints() is named quite well.  You are just providing hints, probably not enough to select anything other than the only voice you have available in the machine.  Adding more voices requires buying them.  Using the speech platform requires using the Microsoft.Speech namespaces.

Comment: @Hans Passant  hello, what means `Using the speech platform requires using the Microsoft.Speech namespaces.`? use for what or you mean in generally, if so, yes guess I know it. But I'm not sure, if it works with exe file for other user, only with english  for example?